# How to Mock Android PackageManager for Espresso Test?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have the following code:

```
fun someFunctionInsideActivity() {
    val intent = try {
        packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("some.app.id")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(webSiteUrl)
        )
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I want to write `Espresso` test for both scenario. I was wondering if its possible to Mock the return of `packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(...)` so that I could test both scenario in test.

Any ideas? Any other way of testing this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.